# material vs materials. Which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

When you talk about a collection of snippets and facts for an article, do you say "material" or "materials"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use "material" (without the "S").

According to Dictionary.com:

> **materials**
>
> The articles or apparatus needed to make or do something.
>
> **material**
>
> A group of ideas, facts, data, etc. that may provide the basis for or be incorporated into some integrated work.

Comment: Hm. I don't really understand what is distinction between these 2 cases.

Comment: Used in this sense *material* is an uncountable noun. e.g. *I have all the material I need to write the article*. Used in other senses *material* is countable. e.g. *It is astonishing what they were able to build with the limited materials they had available*

Comment: Also the def given for _materials_ refers to concrete objects, whereas the def given for _material_ refers to abstract ideas. So, I suppose, if you were gathering both types, you could rightly say that you had the _material_ AND the _materials_ ready.  But I wouldn't recommend it; the listener might not catch your meaning.